# Hot reloading for Electron, works in browser but only live reloads in Electron

Tags: node.js, webpack, electron, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I'm trying to get hot reload to work in Electron, but for some reason it's always refreshing. When I test it in the browser it works perfectly fine though.

I'm trying to make an IDE that has hot reloading for users, and I'm doing it by using child_process.exec per below function in my main process.

```
function simulator(root) {
  let spawn = exec('webpack-dev-server', {
    cwd: path.join(__dirname, '../lib/temp/new-project')
  }, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    let child = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 800,
      height: 600
    });
    child.loadURL('http://localhost:8080');
    child.toggleDevTools();
  })
}
```

Here is my webpack config, pretty much copy of webpack 2's tutorial on hot reloading for react.

```
const { resolve } = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    // activate HMR for React

    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
    // bundle the client for webpack-dev-server
    // and connect to the provided endpoint

    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    // bundle the client for hot reloading
    // only- means to only hot reload for successful updates

    './index.js'
    // the entry point of our app
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    // the output bundle

    path: resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),

    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/'
    // necessary for HMR to know where to load the hot update chunks
  },

  context: resolve(__dirname, 'src'),

  devtool: 'inline-source-map',

  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    // enable HMR on the server

    contentBase: resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    // match the output path

    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
    // match the output `publicPath`

    // port: 8081
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: [
          'babel-loader',
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader?modules',
          'postcss-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    // enable HMR globally

    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    // prints more readable module names in the browser console on HMR updates
  ],
};
```

Index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8080/bundle.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Entry point:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
// AppContainer is a necessary wrapper component for HMR

import App from './components/App';

const render = (Component) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Component/>
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
};

render(App);

// Hot Module Replacement API
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./components/App', () => {
    render(App)
  });
}
```

When I execute webpack-dev-server in my bash terminal in the project directory and go to localhost:8080 it works fine. But executing webpack-dev-server through child_process makes it only do live reload in both electron and the browser on localhost:8080.

Any insights?

Answer (score 0):

works now, didn't change anything. No idea why :shrugs: